# Create odoo model on view level

Tags: python, odoo

can we create a model in odoo so it could not reflect on database level?

For example:

```
class SalaOrder(model.models):
    _name='sale.order'
```

I don't want to create "sale_order" table in database .

Comment: What you mean by "reflect" is a bit unclear. Do it means you don't want the table to be created automatically by odoo, or do you want it to be created but with another name ?

Comment: Yes, I don't want to create table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the comments on `models.py` (odoo/odoo/models.py) you can set `_auto` to `False`.

```
class SalaOrder(model.models):
    _name = 'sale.order'
    _auto = False
```

To comment says

```
_auto = False # don't create any database backend
```

Here are some more details about Odoo models (from the same code):

> Odoo models are created by inheriting:
>
> - :class:`Model` for regular database-persisted models
> - :class:`TransientModel` for temporary data, stored in the database but
>     automatically vacuumed every so often
> - :class:`AbstractModel` for abstract super classes meant to be shared by
>         multiple inheriting models
>
> The system automatically instantiates every model once per database. Those
>       instances represent the available models on each database, and depend on
>       which modules are installed on that database. The actual class of each
>       instance is built from the Python classes that create and inherit from the
>       corresponding model.
>
> Every model instance is a "recordset", i.e., an ordered collection of
>       records of the model. Recordsets are returned by methods like
>       :meth:`~.browse`, :meth:`~.search`, or field accesses. Records have no
>       explicit representation: a record is represented as a recordset of one
>       record.
>
> To create a class that should not be instantiated, the _register class
>       attribute may be set to False.

Comment: A bit of warning here. Odoo always expects a table to be created either by _auto or by your own code. _auto=False on a model is used for report where the table is explicitely created in init method. If you use _auto =False and do not create a table, you'll get warnings in your log files.
To create a model without any table, AbstractModel should be used.